# Display lines that have an odd number of characters using grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Using grep display the lines that have an odd number of characters . Any ideas, I don't know how to get the number of characters from each line, I tried with wc but it only counts the number of characters globally.

Comment: Can you define what "odd number of characters" means ? Better give some sample input and sample output too

Comment: the number of characters in not even

Comment: It sounds as if you want to find a regexp that matches any pair of characters (or, hint, a pair of 'any' characters), turn that into one that matches any number of pairs of characters, and turn that into one which does, or doesn't, match a line composed of only matched pairs of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the lines with odd number of characters only using `grep`:

```
egrep -v '^(..)+$' file
```

The normal thing to do would be to use the modulus operator like so:

```
awk 'length%2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use repetition to find out:

```
grep -v '^\(..\)\+$' file
```

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Oh really?